# How do I remove a Key from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hi All,

I am just trying to learn how to remove the key in Yellow. I will appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: do u want to remove it using webportal or programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call -

```
databaseReference.child("client_request_key/children/"+key).removeValue();
```

If you dont know the key -

```
databaseReference.child("client_request_key/children").orderByChild("first_name").equalTo("KAMAL").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
      databaseReference.child("client_request_key/children/"+key).removeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, HarshitG, It works. I don't know why my question is downgraded. I am always scared to ask question Here. I thought Carl Sagan said: "There is no such thing as a dumb question"?